# Find how many combinations from a matrix are $\le$ k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, matrix-equations

If you are given an $m*n$ matrix $A$ where $m\ge1$ and $n\ge1$, and target $k\ge1$, how would you determine the total number of combinations from the matrix that sum to less than or equal to k such that at least 1 entry from every row must be present in the linear combination?

For example, suppose you wanted to find the number of linear combinations that sum to no more than 10 in the following matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2&3\\
    4&0\\
    2&3\\
    1&2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Because every row must be present in the linear combination, we must find the combinations that sum to no more than 6 (in other words, $m_2n_1$ is by default included in the linear combination. Our answer is 4:
$1*m_1n_1 + 1*m_3n_1 + 1*m_4n_2 = 6$

$1*m_1n_1 + 1*m_3n_1 + 1*m_4n_1 = 5$

$1*m_1n_2 + 1*m_3n_1 + 1*m_4n_1 = 6$

$1*m_1n_1 + 1*m_3n_2 + 1*m_4n_1 = 6$

Comment: i am not sure about linear-algebra relation to this problem, but this looks like combinatoric problem that's solved by generating functions.

$(x^2 + x^3)(x^4+x^0)(x^2+x^3)(x^1 + x^2)\frac{1}{1-x}$ and your looking for coefficient next to $x^k$

Comment: I have a serious problem understanding the problem statement. First, apparently we are only talking about (non-negative?) integers both in the matrix and in the "linear combination". Second, what are those $m_i$ and $n_i$? Third, I have no idea what kind of "linear combination" you mean. You started well by giving an example matrix, but then I never see those number again. The 4 equations at the end are totally not understandable for me.

Comment: hi @lngix, those are indices. Also, the linear combination is because if the target were 64, then the constants won't be one (ex: we could have 10m1n1+10∗m3n1+10∗m4n2) as a combination